# How do you get file path for file when user directory changes?

Tags: java

I have a java app, and the log4j.properties file is in src/com/my/path/props.  On compile, it's copied into classes/com/my/path/props

The file is loaded via PropertyConfigurator.configureAndWatch(user.dir + "/classes/com/my/path/props/log4j.properties").

This all works fine normally, though it's not ideal because of using user.dir (but I do not know another way to reference a file relative to the "application's start directory"). The problem manifests when trying to run this application using an NT Service wrapper. When done this way, the user.dir changes from the application's root dir to wherever the NTService wrapper's exe file is.

My question is: What's the appropriate way to get a the String file path representation of the log4j.properties file in my classes/com/my/path/props/ directory? I realize this would completely break down if the props file were in a jar; but in this case, it's not and is simply a file on the file system.

I've tried new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/my/path/props/log4j.properties").getURI()).getAbsolutePath(), but that fails because on production, the path to the file is actually a UNC path and consequently throws a "URI has an authority component" exception.

How do other people deal with this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused because you said the file is copied to the classpath (i.e. in the classes directory), but then you mention "user.dir". If you are loading the file from the classpath, then "user.dir" is irrelevant. Where do you want the file loaded from?

Comment: it's copied to the classes directory as a result of Eclipse's normal compile process. So it happens that on deployment, the prop file lives in the classes directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took singleshot's advice and kept the properties files out of src and instead in a separate directory which I added to the classpath. In retrospect, this was indeed boneheaded to have configured it the way I did originally.

From there, my problem was getting a File from a URL. I ended up finding what I needed in Commons IO FileUtils, with its [toFile(URL)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#toFile%28java.net.URL%29) method.

The code ended up looking like this:

```
private URL maintenanceConfigPath = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MaintenanceConfig.properties");
....
File f = FileUtils.toFile(maintenanceConfigPath);
....
```

Again, thanks to all for your feedback and for pointing me down a path that got me towards an answer

Answer (score 1):

OK. So... you asked how other people deal with this problem. First, they do not leave it up to Eclipse for where files get placed. They choose where they want them, how they want to access them, and then have their build tool (which unless they are just playing around, should not be an IDE like Eclipse, but rather a dedicated build tool like Maven or Ant) where to place it.

The choice of where you want the file depends on what you want to do with it. If its simply a config file that will never be edited at runtime, you typically place it inside your JAR (which is another practice - applications are placed in one or more JARs, WARs, or EARs, not a classes directory). If the file is to be edited at runtime, which from your "watching" it appears to be the case, you typically put it in a config directory outside your JAR.

How you access it (from the filepath or the classpath) is another choice. Where possible, I favor accessing files from the classpath because it is more portable - and when in a JAR, pretty much required. If that doesn't make sense in your case, then choose a path other than "user.dir" if that is changing when you deploy. You can hard-code it, use an environment variable, a property, a config file, a command line argument, etc. to set the actual path.

Always choose where things go and how you access them. Don't let your tools choose for you. It will make your life easier :-)

Comment: +1. I'm guessing OP is not using classpath precisely because of "watching"

Comment: completely understood. I should've been clearer: I'm using the classes directory because I had no good reason to go somewhere else. Other non-watched props files live there, and I wanted to keep all the properties files together in this application instead of some in the classes directory (I like this convention) and some in a different props dir.

Is there no way in a java class to say "give me a file relative to "me", where "me" is the class?  And is that completely bad to do?

Comment: Classes are on the classpath, so unless you do something very strange, you do not access files relative to classes. You access them relative to the root of the classpath. If your file is in a directory on the classpath, you can access it with your classloader example above (don't use the "user.dir" style). Note that it is not relative to your class - you are simply using your class to get a classloader for accessing the classpath. That should work though.

Comment: Thanks SingleShot... but that's what I am doing: I'm accessing the file using getClassLoader().getResource(), and I can access it successfully, but I need to pass in a the String representation of that file into configureAndWatch(), and that's where this whole thing breaks down. No matter where the properties file lives, I still have the problem of converting the URL from getResource() into a file path that configureAndWatch will understand. Does that make sense?